# Install any application in an ubuntu pod running in Azure Kubernetes using Ansible AWX playbook

Tags: azure, ansible, devops, ansible-awx

I am trying to install python3 in an ubuntu container running on AKS using an Ansible Playbook. Here are the steps I am following in the playbook.

1. Create a pod with ubuntu latest image ( deployment file using the k8s module ).
2. Adding pod name to hosts.
3. Install python3 on the ubuntu container using the below snippet.

[image]

I am getting this error in the console of AWX job:

[image]

Any idea how I can correct this ? Is there another way to directly install python3 using the deployment file of ubuntu pod ?

Comment: Please do not provide code, logs, output, error messages... in images:  it is usually barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, visually impaired people cannot use their voice synthetizer, people trying to help you cannot copy/paste the content if needed, it uses (in best cases...) 1000 times more data volume (e.g. disk space to store, data transfers....) than the equivalent text in code/citation block... and above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary notes:

- Please edit your question and switch your images to code blocks. I explained why in my above comment.
- I'm answering your precise question here. But unless you are in a specific use case (testing a playbook/role/collection, specific development environment....), deploying software with ansible (or actually anything else) inside a running container after its deployment is globally a bad idea. Build an image containing all the tooling you need and deploy it directly.

Now to your problem. **All** ansible modules with the **only exceptions** of `raw` and `script` require python to be installed on the target machine. It looks like this requirement is not met.

Hence you need to use the `raw` module which is specifically made for that (and that you should use **only** for that as a good practice)

```yaml
---
- name: install ansible requirements with the low down dirty raw module
  raw: apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install python3
```

But once again, even in a test use case, you should build and deploy an image already containing the requirements for ansible (i.e. already having python). You can easily use any [official python image from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) for that as a simple example.